# Set Locale - Russian

Tags: php

I'm using setlocale to display dates in Russian.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU');
```

My question is, will ru_RU be enough or is it safer to provide a number of alternative language params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want dates in Russian, you've set the locale for time-related functions to `ru_RU`, so that's basically it.

I'd advise you to set the current locale as a secondary choice for `LC_TIME`, in case `ru_RU` is not available :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU', setlocale(LC_TIME, '0'));
// setlocale() with '0' will return the current settings without applying changes.
```

The current locale setting was set by the system administrator, and it is very unlikely to go unavailable.

Comment: Thanks. But how does your code set it to RU in the first place?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

[setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) affects a lot of things you should answer yourself if these things covers your needs.

It has two params `setlocale ( int $category , array $locale )`

`$ategory` can be(from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)) set to one of these constants:

- LC_ALL for all of the below
- LC_COLLATE for string comparison, see strcoll()
- LC_CTYPE for character classification and conversion, for example strtoupper()
- LC_MONETARY for localeconv()
- LC_NUMERIC for decimal separator (See also localeconv())
- LC_TIME for date and time formatting with strftime()
- LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)

Also look at this quote from manual:

> Returns the new current locale, or FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.